# Modify data pass to purchase order odoo8

Tags: python, odoo

I am creating a module that will allow a customer to specify product (computer) features (RAM,Processor,...etc). At the sale order line the user specifies the product features and if any of those sub-products aren't found a purchase order is created for each one.

I tried to search on odoo modules for the write() operation responsible for this but with no success.

I am using odoo v8

[image: Screenshot from my sale order quotation]

Comment: with aren't found you mean that they dont have stock?. You can do that re-defining the write of sale_order_line. But, there are 2 things that you should take care of:

1) Use virtual stock and not real, because you will be generating a lot of purchase orders if you dont receive asap.

2) When will you do the stock moves of the features?, they wont have relation and no purchase orders will be created again if you dont make a picking out.

Comment: it looks like a good solution . could u please help me with the code . But one question : isn't this method will generate too many unwanted data in the DB

Comment: Not really, you need to make stock move of these products else the stock wont change, so you do need this stored in the DB and its the way that odoo handles the stock so not much to do about that anyway.

and about the code, show me what you have and how you wanna do it and ill help you

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found that I don't write to purchase since my main products are manufactured not purchased so i add a write() to my code for creating my own quotation

Comment: i dont understand what you mean with write in this context, what are you stuck with now?